# Extract all string inside the [] using scala regular expression

Tags: scala

I have a string as below:

```
val prefix= "PREFIX[EB.AR.]"
```

I want to get the value `EB.AR.` from that string .

Anyone please guide me of how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried?, is `PREFIX` always the same?, have you read [this](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/matching/Regex.html)?, Are you having an specific problem?

Comment: yes, prefix always the same, I already tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// The escaped braces ('\[ ... \]') are for matching the literal characters.
// The parenthesis ('(...)') are for making a capturing group.
// The non-escaped braces ('[...]') are for making an or.
// The '+' means 1 or more times.
// The '\w' means any word character.
// The escaped dot ('\.') is for matching the literal character.
val prefix = raw"PREFIX\[([\w\.]+)\]".r

// extracts what is inside the capturing group.
def extract(text: String): String = text match { case prefix(inside) => inside }

extract("PREFIX[EB.AR.]")
// res0: String = EB.AR.
```

For more information about the patterns read the [**javadoc**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
val prefix= "PREFIX[EB.AR.]"

val RE = raw"\[([^\]]*)\]".r.unanchored  //capture everything inside the 1st []
val RE(extractedStr) = prefix            //will throw if no []
//extractedStr: String = EB.AR.
```